# How to configure nginx to map only the first path in URL to a specific directory for php app?

Tags: php, nginx

I'm working on a php web app and want the URLs to be mapped to a folder on the server like this:

```
https://app.com/clientOne/... --> /client/...
https://app.com/clientTwo/... --> /client/...
etc
```

And all folders following `clientOne` and `clientTwo` in the URL exist on my server under `client` E.g. `clientOne/admin/` gets mapped to `client/admin/`, and `clientTwo/app/` gets mapped to `client/app/`.  I want all clients to share the same application, and the application will determine the client from the URL.  (I don't want to deal with subdomains right now.)

My nginx config works only when directories are in the URL.  When I reference specific php files, I get a 404:

```
https://app.com/clientOne/admin/ (works)
https://app.com/clientOne/admin/index.php (returns 404)
```

I've searched and haven't found anyone with this particular issue.  I think I know what needs to be done, but everything I have tried has not worked.  Here is my standard nginx config:

```
    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files       $uri =404;
            include  fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass    unix:/var/run/php-fpm/www.sock;
            fastcgi_index   index.php;
            fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME  $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    }
```

and this:

```
    location ~ ^/(clientOne|clientTwo)/(.*)$ {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /client/$2?$query_string;
    }
```

I'm thinking I need to update the php location block to address my issue and then I won't need the second location block, but everything I have tried has not worked.  I tried changing the try_files in the php location block to this, but it didn't work:

```
            try_files       $uri /client/ =404;
```

Does anyone know how to do this?  Thanks

Comment: You need to reverse the two `location` blocks, so that the `^/(clientOne|clientTwo)/(.*)$ ` regular expression is matched before `\.php$`.

Comment: Thank you!  I had some other location blocks that had to be after the php block so didn't think to move this one to before the php block.